# SharePoint CSOM call failing to small list

Tags: c#, console-application, sharepoint-2013, csom

We have a Console application which makes SharePoint CSOM calls to a list in a SharePoint site in an intranet.

This call works with a list with 1000+ records. However this call is failing when we deployed the Console application in a different machine in the intranet.

It cannot be MaxReceivedMessageSize or MaxParseMessageSize because it works elsewhere.

Is there a machine specific setting that needs to be taken care?

The code looks like this:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(SharePointSiteUrl))
                {
                    clientContext.Credentials = AuthenticationHelper.GetNetworkCredential();
                    var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(RequestsList);
                    var requestIdField = list.Fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("RequestID");
                    var query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                    var items = list.GetItems(query);

                    clientContext.Load(requestIdField);
                    clientContext.Load(items);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (var request in requests)
                    {
                        var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                        var newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                        newItem[requestIdField.InternalName] = request.RequestID;

                        newItem.Update();
                    }

                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    result = true;
                }
```

**ERROR:**

```
AppName: Unhandled Exception: Details: Message:The request message is too big. The server does not allow messages larger than 2097152 bytes.
StackTrace:   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at AppName.SharePoint.SharePointHelper.Method3(List`1 requests)
   at AppName.Program.Method2()
   at AppName.Program.Main(String[] args)
TargetSite:Void ProcessResponseStream(System.IO.Stream)
Source:Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has its own limits for CSOM. Unfortunately, these limits cannot be configured in Central Administration and also cannot be set using CSOM for obvious reasons.

When googling for the issue, mostly a solution is given by setting the ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize property to the desired size.

Call the following PowerShell script from SharePoint Management Shell :

```
$ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
$ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 209715200 
$ws.Update()
```

This will set the limit to 200 MB.

However, in SharePoint 2013 Microsoft apparently added another configuration setting to also limit the amount of data which the server shall process from a CSOM request (Why anyone would configure this one differently is beyond me...). After reading a very, very long SharePoint Log file and crawling through some disassembled SharePoint server code, I found that this parameter can be set via the property ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxParseMessageSize.

We are now using the following script with SharePoint 2013 and it works great:

```
$ws = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 
$ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 209715200 
$ws.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxParseMessageSize = 209715200 
$ws.Update()
```

Comment: Where are these changes made? In the registry, client computer where request is made or SharePoint server itself?

Comment: In SharePoint Server, use SharePoint Management Shell